# how to change the OnClick action of button from code behind

Tags: asp.net, button

I have two div with the same design element, the only different is in the button OnClick action , i used

```
string[] commandArr = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] { ',' });
        string path = "imageUploads\\album\\" + DropOfAlbums.SelectedValue.ToString() + "\\" + commandArr[0] + ".jpg";
        upImgPreview.Src = path;
        imgUploadDesc.Text = commandArr[1];
        LinkButton5.CommandArgument = commandArr[0];
        LinkButton5.Click += new EventHandler(this.confirmUpdate);
        LinkButton5.Text = "update";
        uploadImageDiv.Visible = true;
```

I could change the Text of button ,but the OnClick function I can't change 
.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the same handler for both buttons, use the `CommandArgument` to differentiate between both.

```
private void confirmUpdate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton button = (LinkButton) sender;
    string argument = button.CommandArgument;
    // ...
}
```